# How do I do fixed-point division?

Tags: c#, fixed-point

I've got an 8-byte fixed-point number using longs, with a constant denominator of (1 << 24). How do I do division of two Fixed8 values? Since I'm using C#, I can't simply cast to a larger integer. Or am I thinking too much in the language?

Thanks.

```
public struct Fixed8
{
    private long _numerator;
    public const long DENOMINATOR = 1 << 24;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to calculate `a / b` where `a` and `b` are two `Fixed8` values?

Comment: Sorry, thought that was clear. Yes.

Comment: I've got a faint thought in the back of my head that the calculation would be easier if I used M32.N32. Although that would probably require four separate calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [BigInteger Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) to perform the calculations:

```
public static Fixed8 operator /(Fixed8 a, Fixed8 b)
{
    Fixed8 result;
    result._numerator = (long)( new BigInteger(a._numerator) *
                                new BigInteger(DENOMINATOR)  /
                                new BigInteger(b._numerator) );
    return result;
}
```

*Full code:*

```
public const long DENOMINATOR = 1 << 24;

private long _numerator;

public Fixed8(double value)
{
    _numerator = (long)(value * DENOMINATOR);
}

public static Fixed8 operator /(Fixed8 a, Fixed8 b)
{
    Fixed8 result;
    result._numerator = (long)( new BigInteger(a._numerator) * 
                                new BigInteger(DENOMINATOR)  / 
                                new BigInteger(b._numerator) );
    return result;
}

public static explicit operator double(Fixed8 a)
{
    return (double)a._numerator / (double)DENOMINATOR;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return ((double)this).ToString();
}
```

*Example:*

```
var a = new Fixed8(7);
var b = new Fixed8(1.7);

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.WriteLine(a / b);
```

*Output:*

```
7
1.69999998807907
4.11764705181122
```

Comment: While that's a possibility, BigInteger is slow by nature. I'm hoping for a fast division.

Comment: Unless there's some maths trick to perform the division in 64 bit, you're pretty much stuck with BigInteger or your own implementation of a larger data type. Maybe ask at http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Might help; might get the question closed for being a programming question.

Comment: You'd have to rephrase the question a bit, of course, since your actual problem is not directly programming related. Essentially, you want to compute `(((i * j) modulo 2^64) / k) modulo 2^64` and get the same result as `(i * j) / k`. It might help to split off the sign first.

Comment: Wouldn't ( i * j ) / k also have to be ( ( i * j ) / k ) modulo 2^64? And saying "positive values only" would work?

Comment: When you divide two `BigInteger`, the quotient is kind of "truncated" to a whole number. What if you wanted round to nearest integer instead. As an example `7/4` is `1`, but actually `2` is "closer".

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213267/how-do-i-calculate-i-j-modulo-264-k-modulo-264-and-get-the-same-resu - math.stackexchange.com thread link.

Comment: @dtb: Ok, they're not sure what I'm talking about, I'm not sure what I'm talking about; can you go over to that thread and clarify? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that keeps all the calculations in `long`s.  It might not be quicker, though; I haven't measured.

```
public struct Fixed8
{
    public Fixed8(double value)
    {
        _numerator = (long)(value * DENOMINATOR);
    }

    private long _numerator;
    public const long DENOMINATOR = 1 << 24;

    public static Fixed8 operator /(Fixed8 a, Fixed8 b)
    {
        long remainder;
        long quotient = Math.DivRem(a._numerator, b._numerator, out remainder) * DENOMINATOR;

        long morePrecision = remainder * DENOMINATOR / b._numerator;

        return new Fixed8 { _numerator = quotient + morePrecision };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public long Division()
{
    long result = _numerator / DENOMINATOR;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Look up fixed-point numbers before you answer the question, if you don't know what they are. They're not fractions.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `System.Numerics.BigInteger` is fine. But in this specific case, a `System.Decimal` actually has enough precision. So here's my suggestion:

```
 public static Fixed8 operator /(Fixed8 a, Fixed8 b)
 {
   decimal resultNumerator = (decimal)a._numerator * DENOMINATOR / b._numerator;
   return new Fixed8 { _numerator = Convert.ToInt64(resultNumerator) };
 }
```

Comment: Currently using this; probably not the most efficient, though.

Comment: @NarftheMouse What makes you think it's not the "most efficient"? What efficiency do you need? Is your application spending all its ressources dividing `Fixed8`?

Comment: Sorry; should have clarified. It's a practice exercise I assigned myself. Making it faster is part of the practice exercise. Since I've never managed to take a formal class (outside of some internet tutorial sites), things like that are important.